# Reverting to custom plugin on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I was working on a WordPress site. Seeing a plugin not up to date I had updated that and found that the site was using a custom plugin instead. I don't have any back up. Is there any way to restore to the prior version except rolling back from server?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually download different(previous) version of the plugin itself, by using the `svn` repository, this is the place where all plugin versions are stored.

However if this plugin has been manually modified, and this modification was *not* submitted to the `svn` repository, then the only way to fix the things is to restoring the backup of the server.